# Convert to currency or money format in DB2

Tags: db2, currency, currency-formatting, money-format

I have a column of datatype `dec (16,2)` with a possible value like `20000.00`.
I want the result in comma-separated currency or money format like this: `20,000.00`.

As of now I am planning to divide this by 1000's and concat with comma. But I want to know if DB2 has an inbuilt functionality to covert this. Or any other easier method to convert integer to currency format.

```
select A.Billing_Amount 
from Transaction_Table A with ur;
```

Comment: was your capslock key stuck while typing the question title?

Comment: @MarcB: Sorry Mark. I dint get you. Do I have anything in uppercase?

Comment: Just found something on net. to_char function did my job, and pretty easily. This is what I did trim(to_char(column_name, '9,999.99')) this is very handy and easy to modify :)

Comment: That's formatting, not conversion.  This is something that should be handled at the display/output layer.  How are you running the SQL statement?  Note that, in most cases, the database won't actually have enough information to localize the results (ie, commas are used as the decimal separators in Europe, with the period as the thousands separator).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try:

```
 select decimal(A.Billing_Amount,9,2) from Transaction_Table A with ur;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a distinct UDT to store the column as currency type like the following:

```
 CREATE DISTINCT TYPE CURRENCY AS DEC(15,2) WITH COMPARISONS;
```