# Format double string with thousand separator

Tags: sql, function, format, db2, string-formatting

I need to convert a Double to String and format it with thousand separator and 2 decimal place. I have done the conversion of Double to String in a function. But stuck at formatting the String. Is there any clean way to format the String? I am still using DB2 9.5 so VARCHAR_FORMAT() might not be an option for me.

```
CREATE FUNCTION BELSIZE.DBL2STR_2DP (VAR0 DOUBLE)
    RETURNS VARCHAR(50)

F1: BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE var0_2dp DOUBLE;
DECLARE sVar VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE dec_part VARCHAR(50);

SET var0_2dp = ROUND(VAR0, 2);

SET sVar = CAST(CHAR(ABS(DECIMAL(var0_2dp, 31, 2))) AS VARCHAR(50));
SET sVar = STRIP(sVar, LEADING, '0');

IF VAR0 < 0 THEN
    SET sVar = CONCAT('-', sVar);
END IF;

RETURN sVar;    

END
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377352/how-do-i-format-a-number-with-commas-in-t-sql

Comment: @PhiterFernandes thanks for the link. But I am not using MS SQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852504/convert-to-currency-or-money-format-in-db2

Comment: @PhiterFernandes thanks for the link. I prefer to do the formatting in the function itself instead of creating distinct type.

Comment: What is the reason you're trying to do that in the database? Database is for storing data; formatting is best done at the client.

Comment: @mustaccio I need this function to convert Double to String then concat this String with other strings